# Does a List<T> Contains a property of T?

Tags: c#, list, contains

I got this List :

```
private static List<Type> _AbstractTypes = new List<Type>();
```

and later in my project I got a `string` that corresponds to a Type.FullName.
The thing is that I'd like to check if my string is contained in my List but I don't manage to avoid a loop usable :(
Im looking for something like :

```
_AbstractTypes.FullName.Contains(myString)
```

I am absolutely aware that my previous code is not compilable at all but that's the sort of thing im looking for !
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: So you don't want to use a loop? or you just want help implementing a loop? Because i think with a foreach loop you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Linq, but we are talking about loop-less construct here only, the code under the hood must do a loop, if you want to do it better, you could use `HashSet<T>`.

Linq code could look like this:

```
_AbstractTypes.Any(t => t.FullName == myString);
```

`HashSet<Type>` code could look like this:

```
var types = new HashSet<Type>();
types.Add(typeof(int)); //Fill it with types
types.Add(typeof(double));

//Check by getting types from their string name, you could of course also cache those types
Console.WriteLine("Contains int: " + types.Contains(Type.GetType(intName))); //True
Console.WriteLine("Contains float: " + types.Contains(Type.GetType(floatName))); //False
```

Comment: _AbstractTypes.Any(t => t.FullName == myString); is perfect :)
By "no loop" I was meaning not something with some old-school looking code and your answer is what I was looking for ;) thx!

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy Linq looks modern and cool, so it should do the trick of not looking old-school :-)

Comment: yep, thats exactly what I was looking for :>

Answer (score 1):

This code :

```
bool result = _AbstractTypes.Any(t=>t.FullName == myString);
```

Should do the job.

It will test the predicate against all type until one is satisfied (true is returned), or none (false is returned).

Answer (score 0):

If the list contains elements, you can do something like `_AbstractTypes.First().GetType()`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
_AbstractTypes.Any(t=>t.FullName.Contains(myString))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid looping.

You can do (with looping behind the scenes):

```
bool check = _AbstractTypes.Any(item => item.FullName == myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find out if a type is contained in your list that way:

```
if (_AbstractTypes.Contains(typeof(string)))
{
    // Do Something
}
```